# How can i make a unique page for every video / image uploaded onto my website?

Tags: php, html, node.js

I couldn't find anything on this topic, like I found some dodgy tutorials from 2009 on how to create unique ids, but I want to know how to make the website around that unique id. I want to do it in the "Youtube way".

I want my links to somewhat resemble Youtube links:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1erU-Cwcl2c&ab_channel=Veritasium 
> |----------Youtube----------|----------ID / Data*---------|------Additional Data------|

- I heard that [ID / Data] is a Base64 string, so that's why I wrote ID / "Data", but I'm not sure, I looked it up with an online decoder, and sometimes it gave back something somewhat usable, like "F5", but sometime it was just all Arabic characters..

I'm sorry if I don't respond immediately, I don't check stack overflow that often. 
Also... **S O R R Y   F O R   B A D   E N G L I S H**

Quick reminder: I'm not trying to make youtube2, I just want to see if I can hack something usable together as a side project.

Comment: it's not base64, but it is based on base encoding, like hashids/nanoid (google them), the rest are standard GET params on the main controller for the /watch route, using them to know what to call from db and render.. do you have a specific question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What i think youre after is Routing

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

In particular `Route parameters`

I use Express but you may find something similar using PHP.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing